# Swap can light for wafer not working

Tags: electrical, recessed-lighting

I have a circuit with 3 old recessed can lights (lightoleir)
I just swapped out one for a new wafer led light and all the lights no longer work.
The light I added was at the end of the circuit with just a hot/neutral/ground
The breaker has been turned back on and the wires are wired correctly
The breaker doesn't blow the lights just don't work

Comment: Did you make sure the breaker was turned back on?  The three wires are connected the same as before?

Comment: I edited my original question to provide this information there

Comment: Pics of the wiring?